# Will Activity be destroyed if a fragment has reference to it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, circular-dependency, circular-reference

When do OS decides when to destroy an activity (other than by calling finish)?

If I have an activity that adds a Fragment, and that fragment has a reference to the activity (for example by using an interface listener).

```
Activity >  has fragment > fragment.listener = activity
```

Will the Activity be destroyed by OS when low memory conditions are met? Or should I manually set `fragment.listener = null` first in the fragment's `onDestroy` or `onDetach` method.

The problem I've seen in kotlin is that people are using `lateinit` listeners, so they cannot assign to `null` the listener later.  But I wonder if the system will destroy the fragment, and thus the listener reference will be removed, and thus the activity will be destroyed and fragment manager will be removed, breaking the circular reference.

Comment: The activity will be destroyed (torn down) regardless of what’s holding a reference to it but it will not be freed to the garbage collector if anything has a strong reference to it. It’s generally not good for a Fragment to hold a reference to an Activity because it theoretically can be detached and reattached to a different activity instance, rendering the reference obsolete and leaking that activity.

Comment: This is why they made LiveData and StateFlow

Comment: "Will the Activity be destroyed by OS when low memory conditions are met?" -- [activities are not destroyed due to low memory conditions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html). Your whole process may be terminated due to low system RAM, but that gets rid of everything (activities, fragments, and more).

Comment: @Tenfour04 is there even any valid use case of fragment being attached to a different activity instance? I think only retained fragments did that but they were deprecated. Clearing the reference is just a good idea to ensure fragment can no longer leak any interactions or callbacks into its parent activity after being detached.